# PySide6 Recommended Way to Use QFileDialog

Tags: pyside6, qfiledialog

The [PySide6 `QDialog.exec()` docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.exec_) state to avoid using `exec()`:

> Avoid using this function; instead, use `open()`. Unlike , [open()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.open) is asynchronous, and does not spin an additional event loop. This prevents a series of dangerous bugs from happening (e.g. deleting the dialog’s parent while the dialog is open via ). When using [open()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.open) you can connect to the [finished()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.finished) signal of [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog) to be notified when the dialog is closed.

[`open()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog) is a virtual function, but I don't believe it is pure virtual since I can call it directly on any subclass to immediately open the dialog.

However, [`QFileDialog.open(receiver, member)`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.open) is a bit of a mystery. It connects either the [`filesSelected()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.filesSelected) or [`fileSelected()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.fileSelected) signal (depending on the [`fileMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.fileMode)) to

> a slot specified by `receiver` and `member`

and

> The signal will be disconnected from the slot when the dialog is closed.

Considering the above, is the correct (i.e. recommended) way to use `QFileDialog` like so:

```py
from qtpy import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
        
        self.dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Directory)
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Open folder...')
        
        self.dialog.finished.connect(self.on_finished)


    @QtCore.Slot(QtWidgets.QDialog.DialogCode)
    def on_finished(
        self,
        result: QtWidgets.QDialog.DialogCode,
    ) -> None:
        if result == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            print('Accepted')
        else:  # QtWidgets.QDialog.Rejected
            print('Rejected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    window.dialog.open()

    app.exec()
```

or is `QFileDialog.open(receiver, member)` supposed to be used? If so, how does one use `receiver` and `member`?

**NOTE:** *I'm aware the slot decorator isn't strictly necessary in PySide6, but I add it since it allows me to see at a glance which of my methods are slots vs. just methods.*

Comment: "virtual" doesn't mean that it doesn't do nothing by default or it can't be called, but that it can be overridden and used "internally" on the C++ side (that's an overly simplified explanation, but it's fine for Python requirements).

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I'm aware of that since I said "I don't believe it is pure virtual since I can call it directly on any subclass to immediately open the dialog", but thank you.

Comment: I just pointed it out as I don't know your previous C++ experience , so I assumed that was just a "pure" in literal sense. Btw, there's no absolute "best", for general usage `exec()` is perfectly fine, the core difference (besides the blocking) is the extra event loop: in some rare cases (nested loops of multiple levels of modal dialogs without proper parents) there are some occasions of unexpected behavior that normally don't occur with `open()`. A "strictly" implementation would use the latter, but, in reality, even Qt uses `exec()` in some occasions, including QFileDialog static functions.

Comment: @musicamante Huh, interesting. Good to know! Thanks!...Yeah, I've not yet (knock on wood) had any problems with `exec()`. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Do not deface your question. Once you post it here, it becomes the property of SO under the terms of service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `exec()`, `open()`, and static functions can all be used. Which one you choose depends on your use case, which primarily has to do with whether the dialog is application or window modal. `exec()` is application modal and `open()` window modal, the former being subject to bugs if the dialog is able to delete its parent while the dialog is open. To use `receiver` and `member` requires old-style signal/slot syntax, which is demonstrated below.

###### "Correct" way to use `QFileDialog`?

Per [@musicamante's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337487/pyside6-recommended-way-to-use-qfiledialog#comment129519551_73337487), there is no "correct" way and using either `exec()` or the static functions are acceptable. For example, the [PySide6 QFileDialog docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#more) state

> The easiest way to create a `QFileDialog` is to use the static functions.

and then again, the [PySide6 docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.exec_) also state

> The most common way to display a modal dialog is to call its `exec()` function.

The docs include examples that use `exec()`, and in fact, if you review the [QFileDialog C++ source code](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9ff87af7afa22845b14613521456e53831c0c8ee/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp#L2071), you will see that most of these static methods [ultimately call `exec()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9ff87af7afa22845b14613521456e53831c0c8ee/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp#L2114).

Hence, how `QFileDialog` is used depends on one's needs:

1. On Windows and MacOS, static functions [return a native file dialog](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName), which keeps the look and feel consistent across OS's, but limits you to native functionality unless you pass `DontUseNativeDialog`, in which case a `QFileDialog` is returned:

> By default, a platform-native file dialog will be used if the platform has one. In that case, the widgets which would otherwise be used to construct the dialog will not be instantiated, so related accessors such as `layout()` and [itemDelegate()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.itemDelegate) will return null. Also, not all platforms show file dialogs with a title bar, so be aware that the caption text might not be visible to the user. You can set the `DontUseNativeDialog` option to ensure that the widget-based implementation will be used instead of the native dialog.

2. You must decide whether or not you want the dialog to be [modal](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#modal-dialogs) (application or window) or [non-modal](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#modeless-dialogs) and if you need to do things like delete the `parent` widget during execution of the dialog. On Windows, the static functions [spin a blocking modal event loop that does not dispatch QTimers](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory). Quite literally, [`open()` behaves in a window modal fashion](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9ff87af7afa22845b14613521456e53831c0c8ee/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp#L519), and [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QDialog.open) corroborate this.

Thus, I argue the most important *functional* characteristic to consider when choosing whether to use `exec()` or `open()` is the modality of the dialog and whether or not widgets can be deleted/closed when it is open.

###### `open()`: How Does One Use `receiver` and `member`?

As mentioned in the question, the wording of the [`QFileDialog.open` docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.open) is confusing:

> The specific signal depends is [filesSelected()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.filesSelected) if [fileMode](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.fileMode) is `ExistingFiles` and [fileSelected()](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.fileSelected) if [fileMode](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#PySide6.QtWidgets.PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.fileMode) is anything else.

This is saying `receiver` is passed either a list of files or a single file (depending on the dialog file mode), but the `receiver`/`member` nomenclature may feel odd to those of us who do not recall the [old-style signal/slot syntax](https://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-style-pyqt-signals-and-slots.html), which more closely mirrors how signals and slots are connected in C++ (see [C++ GUI Programming with Qt4, Ch. 2, section "Signals and Slots in Depth"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132354160)):

```cpp
connect(sender, SIGNAL(signal), receiver, SLOT(slot));
```

Indeed, [all `QFileDialog.open()` does](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/9ff87af7afa22845b14613521456e53831c0c8ee/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp#L819) is

- create a signal containing the file or files to send,
- connect the signal to the slot specified by `receiver` and `member`,
- set the signal and slot to be disconnected when the dialog is closed, and
- call `QDialog.open()`

Hence, using `QFileDialog.open()` with `receiver` and `member` requires the old-style slot/signal syntax with the `SLOT` macro and `@Slot` decorator. Without the macro, `Qt` will issue the warning:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: Use the SLOT or SIGNAL macro to connect MyWindow::on_finished()
```

Without the decorator, `Qt` will complain:

```
qt.core.qobject.connect: QObject::connect: No such slot MyWindow::on_finished()
```

Example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from qtpy import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)

        self.dialog.setFileMode(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Directory)
        self.dialog.setWindowTitle('Open folder...')

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_finished(self) -> None:
        for path in self.dialog.selectedFiles():
            print(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()

    window.dialog.open(window, QtCore.SLOT('on_finished()'))

    app.exec()
```

Since `QFileDialog.open(receiver, member)` calls `QDialog.open()` under the hood, you can use that instead. The benefit is this does not require the old-style syntax, with the caveat that you are responsible for connecting signals and properly disconnecting them when the dialog closes.

Answer (score -1):

##### It should be used in situations where the receiver is not the parent of the dialog. In this case, the dialog will be deleted when the receiver is deleted, and the signal will be disconnected automatically.

The below example will crash with error:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton("Click me")
dialog = QFileDialog()

@Slot()
def on_button_clicked():
    dialog.open()

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec()
```

The reason is that the dialog is deleted when the button is deleted, but the signal is still connected to the slot.

---

The solution is to use the second form of open() and pass the button as the receiver:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton("Click me")
dialog = QFileDialog()

@Slot()
def on_button_clicked():
    dialog.open(button, "deleteLater")

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec()
```

---

Another useful situation is in lambda functions:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot

app = QApplication([])
button = QPushButton("Click me")
dialog = QFileDialog()

@Slot()
def on_button_clicked():
    dialog.open(lambda: button.deleteLater())

button.clicked.connect(on_button_clicked)
button.show()
app.exec()
```

There are other situations that the second form of open() can be used, but the above two are the most common.

Comment: In your first answer, you failed to provide references, links to source code, or other 3rd party documents to back up your claims. Once again, you have failed to do so in this answer. The bounty requester asked for  "links to reputable sources". Furthermore, you did not answer how to use `receiver` or `member`.

Please, next time, kindly review my recommendations. I am here to help you write a good answer. Regardless, as you were the first to answer, you received the bounty points.

Comment: Your code does not use the SLOT/SIGNAL macros, so `Qt` issues a warning and your signals and slots are not properly connected and disconnected.